# android windows command processor has stopped working

Tags: android, sdk, prompt, windows-8.1

I am running windows 8.1. I have downloaded and installed the android SDK for version 4.4, 4.1.2. I also installed all of the android SDK Build-tools in the SDK manager. I have Apache Ant version 1.9.2 and JDK 7 installed and I have all of the PATH variables set. My problem is that every time i type android into my command prompt, I get the error saying "windows command process has stopped working" and it closes my command prompt. I have searched high and low for the answer to this question by I have had no luck. So please help me figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone ever runs into this problem. After editing the android.bat file to allow echoing, then going through the commands. I found that the problem was not with android at all. Our company was using a file monitoring/ antivirus system called Lumension. Lumension blocked the copy command from the command prompt. I know its weird but every time I tried to copy even a simple blank .txt file to another location command prompt would shut down. After uninstalling Lumension everything started working again. I'm sure there won't be many people that have this same issue but if you every do I hope this helps you because I spent days trying to track down this issue.